# Cannot find "Resize" in Scope, SwiftUI for dummies problem please

Tags: xcode, swiftui

**Hi following is my code for the News Reader app exercise in swiftui for dummies, I'm getting an error "Cannot find Resize in Scope" any help will be appreciated**

Code:
"

```
import SwiftUI
import URLImage
import URLImageStore


struct Result: Codable {
    var articles: [Article]
}

struct Article: Codable {
    var url: String
    var title: String
    var description: String?
    var urlToImage: String?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    private let url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=49d5bfa113c34ec0af781fab38395996"
    
    @State private var articles = [Article]()
    
    func fetchData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            print("URL is Not Valid")
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResult = try?
                    JSONDecoder().decode(
                        Result.self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.articles = decodedResult.articles
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
            print ("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown Error")")
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(articles, id: \.url) { item in
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                U**RLImage(
                    (( URL(string:item.urlToImage ?? "https://picsum.photos/100")
                        ?? nil
                    )!),
                    delay: 0.25,
                    processors:
                        [Resize(size: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0), scale: UIScreen.main.scale)],
                    content: {
                        $0.image
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .clipped()
                    }
                ).frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)**
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.title)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text(item.description ?? "")
                        .font(.footnote)
                }
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: fetchData)
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
"
```

**Please help in resolving my problem** the problem is I'm getting cannot find "resize" in scope. so the question is: how can I mitigate this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the error is telling you that you are missing the class or struct called Resize. Find where that is in the excercise and put it in a file in your project or in your code above. Most likely at the error is at:

```
"processors:
        [Resize(size: ....."   // <--- here
```

Note there is something strange about the name " U**RLImage". It should probably be "URLImage"